# Particles.js particles not loading up on website

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles.js

It just doesn't show up. The console is also of no help. No particles appear.

Github: https://github.com/AbdulXDG/Prodactiv

I tried linking to the cdn, downloading the files manually and linking it but it doesn't work. I tried everything online but I couldnt fix it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<script src="app.js"></script>` in your `index.html` before closing the `body`.

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked, but there is a new problem now. The particles appear below the typing instead of the whole background. And the button also changed it 's place for some reason

Comment: It could be a CSS issue, you can try and put `position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;` in the `.particles-js-canvas-el` styles and see if it solves the issue.